# Number of ways connecting points on a circle without intersecting

Tags: geometry

Given n points on a circle, labeled 1~n, how many ways are there to connect these points by line segments point-to-point without making any intersections?

The number of line segments could be any including 0, and don't need to be a connective graph.

When two ways have different number of line segments or the end points have different labels on line segments, count them as different ways.

Also, the endpoints of line segments don't count as intersections, and the answer could be an algebraic expression.

My thought is the arrangement of inner part(part that may intersects) do not conflict with the arrangement of outer part(connection of adjacent points, do not intersect), so the answer might be (the arrangement of inner part) * $2^n$. $2^n$ is the outer arrangement, but the inner arrangement seems don't have a pattern.

Down here is some small examples I calculated manually

```
number of points | number of ways
               2 | 2
               3 | 8
               4 | 48  (16*3)
               5 | 352 (32*11)
number of all lines possible: C(n, 2)
number of all intersections: C(n, 4)
```

This problem is from a computer competition but i think it's very mathematical. :D

Comment: Try here - lots of useful information: https://oeis.org/A054726

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! I now can't reply or do other things...

Comment: Are all points have a connection? Does n have to be even?

Comment: Just to highllight, the following two facts can be found in the OEIS article: The generating function is  $$1 + \frac32z - z^2 - \frac z2\sqrt{1 - 12z + 4z^2}$$
And it has the recurrence formula $$a_n = \dfrac{(12n-30)a_{n-1} - (4n-16)a_{n-2}}{n-1}, \quad n>1$$